# How to parse different files depending on the current date in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xml, algorithm, parsing

I have the following problem: I am building an app that is a TV Guide. I am parsing the listing for the channels from a xml file on the internet. This is my code:

```
-(void)loadListing
{
    NSURL *urlListing = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pik.bg/TV/bnt1/29.03.2013.xml"];

    NSData *webDataListing = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlListing];

    NSString *xPathQueryListing = @"//elem/title";

    TFHpple *parserListing = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:webDataListing];

    NSArray *arrayListing = [parserListing searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryListing];

    NSMutableArray *newArrayListing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayListing)
    {
        Listing *shows = [[Listing alloc] init];
        [newArrayListing addObject:shows];
        shows.broadcast = [[element firstChild] content];
    }

    _shows = newArrayListing;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Look at the first row - my file's name is **/.../01.04.2013.xml**
Tomorrow's file will be **/.../02.04.2013.xml** and etc.
How to make it parse different files depending on the current date? Like this: today parses /.../01.04.2013, tomorrow will parse /.../02.04.2013 and etc. ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: find out the current date and then pass the string of current date to urlString.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, Get today's Date with the same format used in URL. (You have to play with separate `date`, `month` and `year` components)
2. Then, Convert that date into a `NSString` object
3. Form a `NSString` like `NSString *strToDay = [NSString
   stringWithFormat:@http://pik.bg/TV/bnt1/%@.xml",strToDay];`
4. Use the string into the `NSURL`, like;
   `NSURL *urlListing = [NSURL URLWithString:strToDay];`

**NOTE** This solution will work only if your URL contains the date format as specified by you.

Comment: Thanks, my friend, this solved my problem! It was not so hard as I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `NSDateFormatter`, property configured, to generate a string of the appropriate format. Use the `NSDate` instance returned by `[NSDate date]` to get today's date, and use the formatter to generate the string. Finally, insert the string representation of the date into the URL string and build an `NSURL` from it.

```c
//  Assuming the TV schedule is derived from the Gregorian calendar
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//  Use the user's time zone
NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

//  Instantiate a date formatter, and set the calendar and time zone appropriately
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorianCalendar];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];

//  set the date format. Handy reference here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

//  [NSDate date] returns a date corresponding to 'right now'.
//  Since we want to load the schedule for today, use this date.
//  stringFromDate: converts the date into the format we have specified
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//  insert the date string into the URL string and build the URL
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pik.bg/TV/bnt1/%@.xml", dateString];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

NSLog(@"URL = %@", URL);
```